# Getting SQL Grammar exception in hibernate for data type date while setting parameter

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to set a parameter to an SQL query via hibernate and the code is as follows

```
public static void upDateCalendarDateToBusinessDay(Session rdsSession){
        String date= getDateBasedOnToday("Today-0","yyyy-MM-dd");
        Transaction tx = rdsSession.beginTransaction();
        try {

            rdsSession.createNativeQuery(DBQueries.UPDATE_DAY_TO_BUSINESS_DAY)
                    .setParameter("date", date)
                    .executeUpdate();
            tx.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Query that I am using is as follows

```
public static final String UPDATE_DAY_TO_BUSINESS_DAY = "update market_data.index_calendar_date icd " +
            " set is_business_day=true where calendar_code = 'CUTOFF_CAL' and calendar_date = :date";
```

The method getDateBasedOnToday returns a date in yyyy-mm-dd format which is then passed to the query UPDATE_DAY_TO_BUSINESS_DAY as a parameter

But I am getting an SQL grammar exception Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: date = character varying Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts even if everything seems proper here.

I tried calendar_date = :date, calendar_date in (:date) and also hardcoded the date value in the query as calendar_date = '2024-02-19'.
For hardcoded value, it worked fine. But for other two I am still getting SQL Grammar exception

Comment: try with " ... date= ?" and setParameter(1, date)

Comment: Didn't get you sorry. Can you elaborate?

Comment: what is there to elaborate on? In your sql, don't put date= :date, but put date= ?
and in your setParameter, don't put ("date", date), but put (1, date)